# lighttpd rewrite rule not working in some browsers

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I'm Having some issues with Lighttpd rewrite options. I have a couple of different domains on the server, and the rewrite rules work just fine on those domins.

However, today I was going to add another domain, and the rewrite rules doesn't work for this domain (but still works good on all other domains).

I have tried many different configurations. But this is my "standard template", which I'm following on all domains. All domains have unique IP's.

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "11.11.11.11|(^|\.)domain\.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/domain"

    url.rewrite-once = (
        "^/news$" => "?page=news"
    )
}
```

When trying to access `domain.com/news` with Google Chrome it changes the URL instantly to `domain.com//?page=news`. But when I try the same with Internet Explorer or Firefox I'm just getting redirected to `domain.com`. When accessing `?page=news` it works just fine.

**Log output from Lighttpd:** (says nothing about URI /news)

```
2014-08-12 20:23:25: (response.c.300) -- splitting Request-URI 
2014-08-12 20:23:25: (response.c.301) Request-URI  :  //?page=news 
2014-08-12 20:23:25: (response.c.302) URI-scheme   :  http 
2014-08-12 20:23:25: (response.c.303) URI-authority:  domain.com 
2014-08-12 20:23:25: (response.c.304) URI-path     :  // 
2014-08-12 20:23:25: (response.c.305) URI-query    :  page=news 
2014-08-12 20:23:25: (response.c.349) -- sanatising URI 
2014-08-12 20:23:25: (response.c.350) URI-path     :  /
```

Anyone!?!? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was browser cache. It had nothing to do with the server configuration at all. Cleaning cookies + cache helped solving this issue.

Having the same issue? Open your browser in private browsing mode (browser will automatically leave any saved cache+cookies unused).